# Domain on one2many field in xml in OpenERP

Tags: xml, odoo

I want to give domain on one2many field in xml and in domain I want to use field of one2many object.

For example:
In Purchase Order Line of Purchase Order form view, I want to show those records whose product_qty is 2. "product_qty" is a field of purchase.order.line

This is my Purchase Order Line

```
<field name='order_line' domain="[('product_qty', '=', 2)]"
```

But its not working. I don't want to give domain in py file when field is define.

Can anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

product_qty is a non-searchable function field. Your domain therefore cannot work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain how can I achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You may try using dynamic function field. See the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13699397/959570) by @AnomA.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am not looking for that kind of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to achieve this you need to create a functional field of type boolean in which the function will return true if product_qty is 2.0, otherwise false. Then use this new field in the domain condition.`<field name='order_line' domain="[('is_qty_2', '=', True)]" >`